# What code i need to edit for valid email on this scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here my code of jquery validation. I have added some fields for required but now i need to valid email in email id field..please tell me what code i need to edit in this script...

My Code Is:

```
$("#ad_form").validate({
                highlight: function(element) {
                    $(element).closest('.formRow').addClass("form-field error");
                },
                unhighlight: function(element) {
                    $(element).closest('.formRow').removeClass("form-field error");
                },
                rules: {
                    fname_a: "required",
                    lname_a: "required",
                    email_a: "required"
                },
                messages: {
                    fname_a: "Please enter your first name ",
                    lname_a: "Please enter your last name",
                    email_a: "Please enter email id"
                },
                errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    error.appendTo( element.closest(".formRow") );
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply like this:

```
 ...rules{
 ...email_a: {
    required: true, 
    email: true
    }
```

EDIT: For more information about it you can go [here](http://jqueryvalidation.org/email-method/).

Answer (score 0):

You can Add Validator method

```
 $.validator.addMethod("emailRegex", function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) ||  /^(\s)?[\w.+-]+@[\w.+-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4}(\s)?$/i.test(value);
    });
```

And in rules you have to add

```
email_a: "required",
emailRegex : true
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("#ad_form").validate({
                highlight: function(element) {
                    $(element).closest('.formRow').addClass("form-field error");
                },
                unhighlight: function(element) {
                    $(element).closest('.formRow').removeClass("form-field error");
                },
                rules: {
                    fname_a: "required",
                    lname_a: "required",
                    email_a:
            {
         required: true,
         email: true
            }

                },
                messages: {
                    fname_a: "Please enter your first name ",
                    lname_a: "Please enter your last name",
                    email_a:
            {
         required: "Please enter email",
         email: "Please enter a valid email address."
            }

                },
                errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    error.appendTo( element.closest(".formRow") );
                }
            });
```